# How do I use www.domain.org/#!/topic/item style URLs and what are they called?

Tags: web-applications, url, url-rewriting

On many sites I see URLs like `www.domain.org/#!/topic/item` in my address bar. For example the new twitter changes the URL into that.

I know what the hash does when you use targets in HTML: `www.domain.org/page.html#topic3` moves the browser viewport to the anchor `<a name="topic3">`.

Also I think that this URL scheme solves the problem of having always the right URL in the address bar on a page with dynamical loaded content.

But how…

- …do I handle those URLs on the server
  side? (mod_rewrite, javascript?)
- …is the technique called?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why Twitter and some popular sites use hash in the address, is that it gives the website the ability to use the Back and Forward button on a content that is dynamically loaded using Ajax. You don't really have to do anything on the server-side, the trick is to catch the address change on the client-side.

There is a popular plugin for jQuery called jQuery History. - http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/ which does the job for you, but you would have to load the content from the server using Ajax and display it in some container on your website.

One note, the ! next to the hash is a way to make search engines be able to crawl your website. More about that on http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: How can search engines crawl a web app, even with the ! in its URL? Do I have to provide a static version for the search engine (and so handle the /#!/-URLs on the server side)? Or does it execute the javascript and thus fetches the dynamic content?

Comment: @Simon I believe that they try to open the URL after the hash. For example if your URL is http://site.com/#!/mentions then it will try to open http://site.com/mentions and view the HTML content returned from that site. But you can read it straight from Google how it works - http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

What you usually do is to pick up the `window.location.hash`, and pass it as a parameter to the server in an AJAX request.

There's the `window.onhashchange` event for finding out when it's changed (hence when to issue a new AJAX request), but not all browsers implement it, so for now you're better off just writing a javascript interval that continuously checks if the hash has changed.

Answer (score 0):

They are used by dynamic web pages as you already said. There are many ways to handle such url requests on the server side.
The form with the exclamation mark is used for SEO I believe.

see [http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html).